# What am I doing wrong here. Python permutations question

Tags: python

Question:
You're given a string N, called the needle, and a string H, called the haystack, both of which contain only lowercase letters a…z.

Write a program to count the number of distinct permutations of N which appear as a substring of H at least once. Note that N can have anywhere between 1 and|N|! distinct permutations in total – for example, the string aab has distinct permutations (aab, aba, and baa).

```
from itertools import permutations
N = str(input())
H = str(input())

perm = list(permutations(N))
counter = 0

for i in range(len(perm)):
    str = "".join(perm[i])
    
    if str in H:
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```

input:

```
aab
abacabaa
```

expected output:

```
2
```

output:

```
4
```

Comment: This would have been obvious if you had done even a little debugging...

Comment: In your own words: how many distinct permutations of `aab` do you think there are? Where the code says `perm = list(permutations(N))`, how many elements do you think will end up in `perm`? (did you check this?) What results do you see? Are those distinct permutations? (Hint: again, what does "distinct" mean?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. This site is not here to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code or make your project work. Stack Overflow is for **answering questions** in order to *understand* a problem, *after you have found* such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the permutations of 'aba' has duplicates due to the presence of more than one 'a'. Your question specifies distinct permutations and so the simplest fix is to cast your permutations to a set instead of a list. This works because a set can only contain unique values.

It is also bad practice to name a variable the same as a built-in function as this will override that function as you did with 'str'.

```py
from itertools import permutations
N = str(input())
H = str(input())

perm = set(permutations(N))
counter = 0

for p in perm:
    string = "".join(p)
    
    if string in H:
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```

You could also simplify the main portion of the code like this

```py
counter = sum(''.join(p) in H for p in set(permutations(N)))
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. We aren't supposed to take questions here that are general code review or a debugging request; it's not your job to find things in the code to improve, but to **answer a question** about a problem **that was clearly identified already**. (Also, you missed one of the logical errors in the first code block, and only accidentally fixed it in the comprehension without apparently noticing or explaining.) Note well that this is **not a discussion forum** (which would be the appropriate venue for providing this kind of help).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What logical error did they miss?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Also, what in the tour or that other page says what you're saying? I don't see it and I think the answer is alright. What **are** we supposed to do with "debugging request" questions?

Comment: @KellyBundy the tour explains that the site is a library of high-quality Q&A; to serve that purpose, we exclude such debugging questions. The how-to-answer page explicitly says to answer well-asked questions and describes the standard reasons for question closure, including the Needs More Focus reason that applies to typical debugging and homework questions. We are supposed to close such questions, and I am fairly sure this is not at all the first time I have explained this to you. I was mistaken about the logical error; I somehow misread the code.

Comment: (Although for this question I instead voted "caused by a typo", on the basis of the detailed description: "this [question] was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers." The problem in the code can't be characterized in a way that makes it searchable for anyone else who had the same problem, and people are unlikely to even have the same problem in a recognizable way, because it is an idiosyncratic logical error - the result of failing to reason about the code, *not a result of a lack of knowledge or understanding of Python*.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not sure what you mean with "such" debugging questions, but *"questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")"* are generally ok here if they *"include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"*. Granted, the question's code could be shorter, but I think it's short enough and the question fits the criteria. Both of my quotes come from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Neither of the two pages you linked to even mentions debugging.